# PHP System return 127 error code

Tags: php, linux, macos

I've tried to backup my database with the following php code on mac Sierra:

```
$command = "mysqldump --opt -u root -proot si_clinic_pos > clinic.sql";
system($command, $output);

if($output != 0) {
  echo $output;
}else {
  echo 'Database saved';
}
```

The output is "127", but if I tried to execute the "mysqldump --opt -u root -proot si_clinic_pos > clinic.sql" inside terminal, it's working fine.

what's wrong with it, could you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/bin/sh could not be executed, the exit status will be that of a command that does exit(127).I advice you run your PHP program as root user.

Comment: I just found the solution just add /usr/bin in front of mysqldump. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The solution to the problem is to specify the full path to the executable file you want to run.

So, in this specific case, instead of:

```
$command = "mysqldump ...";
```

you need to have:

```
$command = "/usr/bin/mysqldump ...";
```